# Javascript preload - onload inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, image-preloader

What is the difference between

```
<img id="el" src="HD.jpg" onload="loadImage();">
function loadImage() {...}
```

and

```
<img id="el" src="HD.jpg">
document.getElementById('el').onload=loadImage();
```

?

Example 1 triggers the function when the image is fully loaded, example2 triggers it even before the first bit of image is loaded. Isn't it supposed to be the same thing ?

The difference is hard to spot with a full speed internet access but obvious with a narrow one.

Notice that

```
document.getElementById('el').src.onload=loadImage();
```

doesn't work either.

Thanks

edit: sorry for the approximative post title, don't hesitate to suggest a proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something quite different from what you think you're doing: you are assigning the **value** returned by `loadImage` to `..onload` member of the `img` element.

What actually happens is that when your **script** loads, it assigns the result of calling `loadImage()` function (this is why you see it run before any images), which is most likely `undefined` to `img.onload` handler, thereby disabling it.

To do what you want, you need to assign **a function** to `img.onload` handler - for example - just wrap in another function:

```
document.getElementById('el').src.onload = function() { loadImage(); };
```

or you can directly assign your function as a handler. It nicely illustrates why it didn't work before, although I wouldn't recomend it:

```
document.getElementById('el').src.onload = loadImage;
```

(note missing `()`)